# $\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos6x-\cos4x}x\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I am not able to solve this integral. Please someone help.
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos6x-\cos4x}x\,dx$$

Comment: you mean $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{0}^x\frac{\cos(6t)-\cos(4t)}{t}dt$$

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html

Comment: yes i mean this

Comment: Can it be solved using some concept of laplace ?

Comment: the result should be $$-\log\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Do you have proof for this answer ?

Comment: i have looked at the link above

Comment: The indefinite integral is in terms of the [Cosine Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html).

Comment: Have you showed or, can you assume, that this integral exists and is finite?

Answer (score 2):

Let $a,b,c>0$
$$f(a) = \int_0^\infty\frac{(\cos bx-\cos cx)e^{-ax}}x\,dx$$

By differentiation

$$f'(a) = \int_0^\infty(\cos cx-\cos bx)e^{-ax}\,dx = \frac{a}{c^2+a^2}-\frac{a}{b^2+a^2} $$

Now integrate 
$$f(a) = \frac{1}{2} \log \left( \frac{c^2+a^2}{b^2+a^2}\right)$$

$$f(0) =\int_0^\infty\frac{(\cos bx-\cos cx)}x\,dx= \log \left(\frac{c}{b}\right)$$